# How to understand “wouldn’t” here

Tags: meaning, phrases, meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

> “Ah, poor James!” she said. “God knows we done all we could, as poor as we are—***we wouldn’t see him want anything while he was in it***.”

I just interpret the sentence “ we wouldn’t see him want anything while he was in it.” as: when he was alive, he wanted nothing that we knew.

That sounds strange. And I find some book will translate it to the meaning like “when he was alive, we gave all we can to him.” Or “when he was alive, we never let him lack of anything” I think if the sentence can interpret like “when he was alive, he wanted nothing that we knew”(there is a under meaning that “we had given all we can give so that he wanted nothing” )

Comment: *we wouldn’t see him [blah blah]* means *we weren't prepared to allow him to [blah blah]* (i.e. - it wouldn't have been acceptable to us if he lacked for anything - we'd have done whatever we needed to to ensure he had everything he could possibly want).

Comment: *I wouldn't see my child go to school in dirty clothes* = *I'll make sure my child *doesn't* go to school in dirty clothes*.

Comment: The key is not the word *wouldn't*, but see = allow.

Comment: I'd say that it has a meaning similar to 'allow' or 'permit' as in, roughly, "We wouldn’t willingly allow/permit him to want anything while he was in it.”

Answer (score 3):

There is no special meaning to *wouldn’t* in this sentence. What might be confusing is that *see* means *allow* here:

> **see**, *v.*
> **25.** *transitive*. In expressions of preference or desire, as *want to see*, *would see*, *hope to see*, *would rather see*, etc. (with
> object and complement denoting an event or situation): to be willing
> to witness; to want (something to happen or be the case). Also in
> extended use: to allow or permit (something to happen or be the
> case).
>  <sub>Source: [Oxford English Dictionary](https://oed.com)
> (login required)</sub>

And to *want for* something means to *lack* something:

> **want**, *v.*
> **3.**
> **c.** *intransitive*. to want for: (in negative constructions with *not*, *never*, etc.) to suffer from the want of, to be without, to lack. Frequently in *to want for nothing*: to have all the necessaries
> or comforts of life.
>  <sub>Source: [Oxford English
> Dictionary](https://oed.com) (login required)</sub>

So:

> *Even though we are poor, we wouldn’t allow him to lack anything while he was in [this world].*

Comment: Oh! Super thanks!!!